# Nested Many to Many Relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have the table structures as

**products** id

**packs** id

**pack_products** pack_id, product_id

**pack_optional_products** pack_id, product_id

So in the above table, `pack` will have 2 type of `products`, `compulsory products` and `optional products`, mean if customer buy the `pack` the products which are attached in that pack as compulsory will automatically ordered, but customer also can see if there is any optional product in the pack so customer can also buy that product too.

Now to manage orders I have the following table.

**orders** id, customer_id

**order_pack** order_id, pack_id

Here everything works fine, using `attach` method as `$order->packs()->attach($pack["pack_id"]);`

So here problem starts ( when I tried to add optional ordered products in the ordered pack), to manage optional products order, I have created the following table

**order_pack_product** order_id, pack_id, pack_optional_product_id

I have created a model as.

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    //
    public function packs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Pack::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('name');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ParentCustomer::class);
    }
}

class OrderPack extends Model
{
    //
    public function optionalProducts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PackOptionalProduct::class, 'order_pack_product')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And then I call the method as.

```php
$order->packs()->optionalProducts()->attach($optionalProduct["pack_optional_product_id"]);
```

and I'm getting this error.

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::optionalProducts()
>   in file
>   /.../....../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php
>   on line 50

SO complete code related to above tables will be this.

```php
$order = new Order();
$order->parent_id = $parent->id;
$order->school_id = $schoolId;
if($order->save()){
    foreach($json["packs"] as $pack){
        $order->packs()->attach($pack["pack_id"], ["child_name" => $pack["child_name"]]);
        foreach($pack["optional_products"] as $optionalProduct){
            $order->packs()->optionalProducts()->attach($optionalProduct["pack_optional_product_id"]);
        }
    }
    return response()->json(["status" => "ok", "order_id" => $order->id]);
}else{
return response()->json(["status" => "failed"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`optionalProducts()` is method of model, not of relation `packs()`.

Method `$order->packs()` - returns relation object, attribute `$order->packs` - returns collection of pack models.

You need to iterate trough collection, to attach optionalProducts to every one pack model.

```
foreach($pack["optional_products"] as $optionalProduct){
  foreach($order->packs as $item){
     $item->optionalProducts()->attach($optionalProduct["pack_optional_product_id"])
  }
}
```

Perhaps, this code will not correct the error, then you need to correct your code logic.